# Can I call a macro from function in ftl

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a function say

```
[#function func a]
   [@print_name "john doe"/]
[/#function]
```

I have a macro say

```
[#macro print_name name]  
  ${name}  
[/#macro]
```

Is it valid to call the macro from the function and will it print anything in the page?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that, but the macro output will be silently dropped if you just call the macro. Usually, if you need to call a macro from a function and return its output as the function result then something is off there. (Calling functions from macros is usual, but the opposite is a not.) But it's doable:

```
[#function func a]
   [#local r][@print_name "john doe"/][/#local]
   [#return r]
[/#function]
```

Note that the return value won't be a string if you are using the auto-escaping feature of 2.3.24 with an escaping output format (like HTML). Then it will be of type "markup output" instead (to prevent double escaping).